# WMI Performance Counters show zero, but Task Manager shows values

Tags: powershell, wmi

I thought Task Manager used the WMI performance counters to calculate things like disk usage per process. However, running a PowerShell script that queries Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process, I get the right process and some data filled in--but the relevant values I'm interested in are all zero. (See image.)

What I want to do is simply get (or calculate) the kind of data that Task Manager shows, and then save the data for graphing and/or decision purposes. (e.g. For learning purposes, killing off a program that is using 100% CPU or 16 GB of RAM.)

[image: Task Manager vs WMI]

Running in Windows 10 (Pro). I just tried running as administrator and no difference. Powershell version is 5.1.

Q: **So why are these values zero?** And, if Task Manager is getting these values... what API is it using if not WMI?

Comment: I think the problem is the sample interval... see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/06/02/how-to-read-performance-counters-ryan-byington/)... The sample/Explanation is in c#.. but you might also use the ```get-counter``` cmdlet, where you can pass the sampleInterval and maxsamples..

Comment: If you want to save it for graphing ... why not just use the Resource Monitor/Performance Monitor which would also allow you to record that data?

Comment: I want to learn specifically WMI and Windows internals. And I don't like not knowing why something is broken / giving unexpected results.  I'm going to look into that sampling interval now.